# Second Chance Page Replacement

Tags: operating-systems, paging

In the second chance page replacement algorithm, if a page's reference bit is already set to 1, and the next page in line of the reference string is the same page, does the reference bit stay at 1 or is it reset to 0?

Answer (score 1):

The reference bit stays at 1, it is set to 0 only in two circumstances, when the page is read from disk, or when the algorithm gives a page a second chance.